# SQL Date range comparison between two tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables. One is calendar table with a date range. The other table has dates. I want to select the dates for which there is no data after comparing with Calendar table. for example:

```
    Declare @Calendar table
(
[Month] varchar(5),
CalDate varchar(10)
)
INSERT into @Calendar values ('May', '05/14/2017')
INSERT into @Calendar values ('May', '05/15/2017')
INSERT into @Calendar values ('May', '05/16/2017')
INSERT into @Calendar values ('May', '05/17/2017')
INSERT into @Calendar values ('May', '05/18/2017')
INSERT into @Calendar values ('May', '05/19/2017')
INSERT into @Calendar values ('May', '05/20/2017')

select * from @Calendar
Declare @ReportTable table
(
ReportID int,
ReportName varchar(10),
ReportData int,
ReportDate varchar(10)
)
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('3456', 'MyReport01', 4563, '05/17/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('3456', 'MyReport01', 6553, '05/18/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('3456', 'MyReport01', 432, '05/19/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('3456', 'MyReport01', 123, '05/20/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('7888', 'MyReport02', 9088, '05/14/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('7888', 'MyReport02', 4545, '05/15/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('7888', 'MyReport02', 144, '05/16/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('7888', 'MyReport02', 676, '05/17/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('7888', 'MyReport02', 4454, '05/18/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('7888', 'MyReport02', 2324, '05/19/2017')
INSERT into @ReportTable values ('7888', 'MyReport02', 68467, '05/20/2017')
select * from @ReportTable
```

I want to return a 0 if for any ReportID there are missing dates in @ReportTable. As you can see for ReportID 3456 there are missing dates. Please guide how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like you need an outer join.

Comment: Select ReportID,ReportDate 
from '@Calendar' FULL OUTER JOIN '@ReportTable'
on ReportDate = CalDate
order by ReportID,ReportDate --doesn't work --sorry added quotes since does not let me put symbols

Comment: Alernatively,  I could write a while lop. Not sure if that is the best way       select caldate from '@Calendar' where caldate not in
(select ReportDate 
from '@ReportTable' 
where ReportID=3456)

Answer (score 0):

The key thing here is to get to where there is one row for each Report - Date combination.  You can get that by doing this:

```
SELECT ReportTypes.ReportID, ReportTypes.ReportName, c.CalDate
FROM @Calendar c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ReportID, ReportName 
                FROM @ReportTable) as ReportTypes
ORDER BY ReportTypes.ReportID, ReportTypes.ReportName, c.CalDate
```

Results:

```
ReportID    ReportName  CalDate
3456        MyReport01  05/14/2017
3456        MyReport01  05/15/2017
3456        MyReport01  05/16/2017
3456        MyReport01  05/17/2017
3456        MyReport01  05/18/2017
3456        MyReport01  05/19/2017
3456        MyReport01  05/20/2017
7888        MyReport02  05/14/2017
7888        MyReport02  05/15/2017
7888        MyReport02  05/16/2017
7888        MyReport02  05/17/2017
7888        MyReport02  05/18/2017
7888        MyReport02  05/19/2017
7888        MyReport02  05/20/2017
```

Then, you just add in the data:

```
SELECT ReportTypes.ReportID, ReportTypes.ReportName, 
    ISNULL(r2.ReportData, 0) AS ReportData, C.CalDate
FROM @Calendar c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ReportID, ReportName 
                FROM @ReportTable) as ReportTypes
         ON 1 = 1
    LEFT JOIN @ReportTable r2
        ON ReportTypes.ReportID = r2.ReportID 
            AND c.CalDate = r2.ReportDate
ORDER BY ReportTypes.ReportID, ReportTypes.ReportName, c.CalDate AS ReportDate
```

You have to use CalDate, since ReportDate will be null some of the time.

This gives these results:

```
ReportID    ReportName  ReportData  ReportDate
3456        MyReport01  0           05/14/2017
3456        MyReport01  0           05/15/2017
3456        MyReport01  0           05/16/2017
3456        MyReport01  4563        05/17/2017
3456        MyReport01  6553        05/18/2017
3456        MyReport01  432         05/19/2017
3456        MyReport01  123         05/20/2017
7888        MyReport02  9088        05/14/2017
7888        MyReport02  4545        05/15/2017
7888        MyReport02  144         05/16/2017
7888        MyReport02  676         05/17/2017
7888        MyReport02  4454        05/18/2017
7888        MyReport02  2324        05/19/2017
7888        MyReport02  68467       05/20/2017
```

Comment: The query works, but could you please explain what INNER JOIN ...ON 1 = 1 means?

Comment: Basically, it joins on everything.  You need to join each date on each report id, and that's how you can do that.

Comment: You should use *CROSS JOIN* instead of INNER JOIN with condition 1 = 1

Comment: @SilverFish So, did this work?  If so, can you accept the answer?